# SSSD storing wrong shell in cache

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I am using SSSD to authenticate users on Linux against a local Active Directory server (Windows). It works fine, this is my config:

```
[sssd]
domains = my.domain
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/my.domain]
ad_domain = my.domain
ad_server = my-dc.my.domain
krb5_realm = MY.DOMAIN
realmd_tags = joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = true
auth_provider = ad
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = true
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = true
use_fully_qualified_names = false
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = IT
```

The problem is: we have one user who wants `zsh`. So I changed the users loginShell attribute to `/usr/bin/zsh`. This works fine the first time the user logs in. But as soon as the user has logged in and I do `getent passwd username`, it says the user's shell is `/bin/bash`. So when the user logs out and in again, indeed `bash` is used as shell.

When I do `sss_cache -u username`, the shell is set correctly again and the user gets the correct shell on login. I do not want to disable caching because any domain controller downtime should not have an impact on the Linux user logins.

I tried to remove `default_shell`, but it only changes that the default shell is empty instead of `/bin/bash`, so same behaviour.

Comment: Where do you set `/usr/bin/zsh` as shell for the user if not via `ldap_user_shell`?

Comment: loginShell attribute in Active Directory.

Comment: Ah, `ldap_user_shell` defaults to `loginShell`, sorry. Try setting `ad_enable_gc = false` in `[domain]` (for testing only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other answer is completely wrong, here is the actual solution (from https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/sssd-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/BXFRHRI5VCLTQNE565ZVGZTEGALSNNJY/):

> I wonder if SSSD is connecting to the Global Catalog for some lookups
>   but not others, which yields the POSIX attributes as 'removed' when SSSD
>   looks up the info in GC and effectivelly removes them from the cache.
>
> Setting:
>       `ad_enable_gc = false`
>   in the `[domain]` section would prove if this hypothesis is true.

So this is the solution, disable the Global Catalog lookups. Many thanks to [@Lennie](https://serverfault.com/users/255884/lenniey) who  suggested this also in the first place but I didn't do it until now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use default in nss section.

```
[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash
```

And override using `override_shell = <your shell>`

```
override_shell (string)
    Override the login shell for all users. This option can be specified globally in the [nss] section or per-domain.
```

Edit1: for group specific changes

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains=DOMAIN_GROUP1,DOMAIN_GROUP2,DOMAIN

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/DOMAIN_GROUP1]
id_provider = ad
ad_domain = mydomain.local
ad_server = mydc01.domain.local,mydc02.domain.local,mydc03.domain.local
# Restrict to group members
ldap_user_search_base = DC=domain,DC=local?subtree?(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local)
# Shell
override_shell = /shell/path/for/group1
# Homedir
override_homedir = /home/%u

#same way for other groups
[domain/DOMAIN_GROUP2]
..........
..........
..........
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This overrides for *all* users, not only one.

Comment: updated answer. Not sure if you want that way.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really help if I manually override the shell. The whole point of this is central login management, not individualized.